# Como obter id do elemento a partir do método find?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou clonando uma linha na tabela, eu consigo inserir um novo valor ao `id`, porém gostaria de concatenar um novo valor ao `id` já existente.

```js
$("#addRow").click(function() {
  $clone = $('#tabela tbody>tr:last')
    .clone(true)
    .insertAfter('#tabela tbody>tr:last');

  $clone.find('input').attr({
    'data-id': $('#tabela tbody>tr').length,
    'id': $('#tabela tbody>tr').length
  });

  $clone.find('input').val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabela">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="nome-1" id="nome-1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="funcao-1" id="funcao-1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="setor-1" id="setor-1" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="addRow">AddRow</button>
```

A cada adição de uma nova linha, o `id` deve ser:

```
nome-2
funcao-2
setor-2
...
nome-10
funcao-10
setor-10
```

Comment: Não basta fazer: `'id': "test-" + $('#tabela tbody>tr').length`?

Comment: Esse é apenas um exemplo, @AndersonCarlosWoss. Haverá N inputs e dessa forma fica inviável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for apenas para concatenar, pode fazer algo como:

> Fiz com que o `id` aparecesse como valor do `input` para facilitar a visualização dos mesmos.

```js
$("#addRow").click(function() {
  $clone = $('#tabela tbody>tr:last')
    .clone(true)
    .insertAfter('#tabela tbody>tr:last');

  $inputs = $clone.find('input');

  $inputs.each($i => {
    $input = $($inputs[$i]);

    let id = $input.attr("id");
    let len = $('#tabela tbody>tr').length;

    $input.attr({
      'data-id': len,
      'id': id.slice(0, id.indexOf("-")+1) + len
    });

    $input.val($input.attr("id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabela">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="nome-1" id="nome-1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="funcao-1" id="funcao-1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="setor-1" id="setor-1" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="addRow">AddRow</button>
```

Mas assim gerará `id`'s bem longos se o número de campos se estender.

Comment: Dessa forma, virá o primeiro índice dos inputs em `$input.attr("id")` e não o corrente.

Comment: Na verdade ele sempre busca o `id` do último `input` inserido e concatena o número total de `input`'s no mesmo. De acordo com sua pergunta, é isso que você precisa.

Comment: Acrescentei alguns inputs para a simulação, @Anderson.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, adicionei os campos à resposta. Veja se assim atende à sua necessidade.

Comment: Corrigi agora a geração dos `id`'s. Ficou bem confuso isso porque na pergunta você disse apenas concatenar com o valor atual e isso não implica em alterá-lo, apenas adicionar ao final. Agora ficou da maneira esperada, acredito eu.

Answer (score 0):

O negócio é automatizar o possível. No caso, uma expressão regular pode extrair o número da linha anterior, incrementá-lo, e então gerar uma função que automaticamente converte o atributo de modo que o número posposto seja o número calculado. Em termos concretos:

```
$("#addRow").click(function() {
  // criar a linha nova
  var $clone = $('#tabela tbody>tr:last')
    .clone(true)
    .insertAfter('#tabela tbody>tr:last');

  // número novo
  var newnum = parseInt(
    $clone.find('input')[0].id.replace(/.*-([0-9]+)$/, '$1'),
    10
  ) + 1;
  // função que substitui o atributo "a" do elemento "e"
  // de modo que o número no fim se torne "newnum"
  var repl = function (e, a) {
    $(e).attr(a,
      $(e).attr(a).replace(/^(.*-)[0-9]+$/, "$1" + newnum)
    );
  }
  // para cada controle, substitua os atributos
  // necessários de acordo com o padrão
  $clone.find('input').each(function (i, e) {
    repl(e, 'data-id');
    repl(e, 'id');
    // etc.
    $(e).val($(e).attr("id"));
  });
});
```